# Comma separated Values

Tags: sql, mysql

How  can i fetch this query using mysql?

**Table1:**

```
id : nos

1   12,13,14
2   14
3   14,12
```

**Table2:**

```
id : values

12   PHP
13   JAVA
14   C++
```

**Now , I want output like this:**

```
1   PHP, JAVA, C++
2   C++
3   C++, PHP
```

Comment: Quite hard to read, but do you really mean that in Table1 there are three rows. In first one has the varchar value "12, 13, 14"?

Answer (score 9):

Not tested but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT table1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.values)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.nos)
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Comment: Hi soulmerge,,
wow it is working fine now..thanks for you swift reply

Comment: I must say, I'm impressed, if I could +2 or even +100 I would.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way that I know of to achieve that in SQL. You should instead have a 1 to N relationship to represent those lists. Something like:

Table 1: (just ids)

- 1
- 2
- 3

Table 1.1: (map ids to values in their list)

- 1, 12
- 1, 13
- 1, 14
- 2, 14
- 3, 14
- 3, 12

Comment: Is there any other way without changing the table? can i use stored procedure for this?

Comment: Come on, just because you don't know a way to do it in Sql doesn't mean a) it can't be done and b) you should suggest something with nastily designed tables.

Comment: @PintSizedCat: I didn't say it can't be done, and that's why I said "that I know of". And anyway, this is a very common approach to relate rows in a table to several rows in another table. I found the FIND_IN_SET solution interesting, and I believe it better suits this problem.

Comment: If this is a common solution to this 'problem' i'll bloody eat my shoe!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work in mySQL but in SqlServer you could create a function:

```
create function dbo.replaceIdsWithValues
(
    @inIds varchar(50)
)
returns varchar(50)
as
begin
    declare @ret as varchar(50)
    set @ret = @inIds
    select @ret = replace(@ret,cast(id as varchar),theValues) from t2
    return @ret
end
```

and then simply call:

```
select id, nos, dbo.replaceIdsWithValues(nos) from t1
```

that assuming your tables structure:

```
create table t1 (id int, nos varchar(50))
create table t2 (id int, theValues varchar(50))
```

You can test the full example

```
create table t1 (id int, nos varchar(50))
create table t2 (id int, theValues varchar(50))
insert into t1(id, nos)
select 1, '12,13,14'
union all select 2, '14'
union all select 3, '14,12'

insert into t2(id, theValues)
select 12, 'PHP'
union all select 13, 'JAVA'
union all select 14, 'C++'

select id, nos, dbo.replaceIdsWithValues(nos) from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Intended this as comment but it is getting long.

[SoulMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44562/soulmerge) answer(+1) is specific to MySql, which the question was intially intended. Please see the edits for the initial question.

Seems the question again got edited for the MY-SQL, but anyway.

While you can achieve this in [MS SQL by using PATINDEX](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3071531/Using-SQL-Servers-CHARINDEX-and-PATINDEX.htm), I am not sure you can do it this in oracle.

I think it would be better to restructure the tables as suggested by  [jo227o-da-silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46329/jo227o-da-silva)(+1).

Answer (score 0):

Although not completely relevant to the subject (MySQL), but will help others finding the question by title, in MSSQL server this can be achived using the FOR XML hint and some nasty string replacements.

I'll post up some code when I find it...