# Comma separated Values - Problem

Tags: sql

I asked a question [**before**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696675/comma-separated-values) and received this answer:

```
SELECT  table1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.values)
FROM    table1
INNER JOIN
        table2
ON      FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.nos)
GROUP BY
        table1.id
```

But I have another field `nos1` (with multiple values) in `table1` that also pointing to `table2`, I use it like this :

```
 SELECT  table1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.values),GROUP_CONCAT(table2.values)
 FROM table1  INNER JOIN table2 ON
 FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.nos),
 INNER JOIN table2 ON
 FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.nos1),
 GROUP BY table1.id
```

, but it is not working properly. I am not getting how to use in this situation.

Here is my data and desired resultset:

Table1:

```
id:   no              nos1

1     14,15,16        17,18
```

Table2:

```
id     value

14     PHP 
15     JAVA       
16     C++  
17     mysql  
18     mysql server
```

Output:

```
id     no               nos1

1      PHP, JAVA, C++   mysql, mysql server
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  table1.id,
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(table2.values)
        FROM    table2
        WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.no)
        ) AS no,
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(table2.values)
        FROM    table2
        WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.nos1)
        ) AS nos1
FROM    table1
```